# Moments of Limited lognormal distribution

Tags: lognormal-distribution, moments

How do you calculate the moments of a lognormal distribution for values contained between two boundaries, given the distribution is also displaced by an amount?  In insurance context, if the losses conform to a lognormal distribution plus a fixed amount, and we want to calculate the mean and standard deviation between a deductible and limit?

Answer (score 1):

If $Y$ is log-normal with parameters $\mu,\sigma$ truncated to the interval $(e^a, e^b)$, then $X=\ln Y$ is truncated normal on the interval $(a,b)$.  The moment generating function of $X$ is then known to be
$$
M_X(t)=e^{\mu t + \sigma^2 t^2 / 2}  \left[ \frac{ \Phi(\beta- \sigma t) - \Phi(\alpha - \sigma t)  }{\Phi(\beta) - \Phi(\alpha) }  \right] ,
$$
where $\alpha=(a-\mu)/\sigma$ and $\beta=(b-\mu)/\sigma$ (see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution)).  Hence, the $r$'th moment of $Y$ is then given by
$$
E(Y^r)=E((e^X)^r)=E(e^{rX})=M_X(r).
$$

Comment: Thanks for this.  Would you be able to expand as to what the mean and variance are for a lognormal distribution with parameters (μ,σ), with a shift displacement of D for the interval (a,b)? Thanks.

Comment: @Joe A shift displacement of D only, affect $EY$ and not the standard deviation of $Y$.

Comment: I agree for unlimited losses, but if I run a simulation on a lognormal distribution, using the simulated result and in scenario 1 have no displacement and in scenario 2 add a displacement amount, then partition the resultant value between a deductible and limit (same applied to each), the standard deviation differs.

Comment: @MattF. Yes, you're of course right, now it's fixed.